# css: how to disable the ability of clicking a link

Tags: html, css

I have the need to disable a link via css, can this be done if the link is visible and holds a valid 'href' attribute value?

html:

```
<a class="theLink" href="https://ebay.com">link</a>
```

css:

```
.theLink{...?}
```

Comment: Please search before you ask a question, there is an already existing answer that is easily found by a simple search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can disable it!

html:

```
<a class="theLinkDisabled" href="https://google.com">link</a>
<br>
<a class="theLinkActive" href="https://google.com">link</a>
```

css:

```
.theLinkDisabled{
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor:default;
}

.theLinkActive{
    pointer-events: auto;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to know how to reactivate them, works perfect

Answer (score 1):

```
.thisLink{
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qfL97png/1/)